# requestFullscreen or webkitRequestFullscreen no longer working in UIWebView for iOS 8

Tags: ios, html, ios8, uiwebview, webkit

I just looked into a reported bug here in an app, and it looks like `requestFullscreen` or `webkitRequestFullscreen` no longer works on UIWebView in **iOS 8**.

It also no longer seems to respect the `allowsInlineMediaPlayback` property being set to NO.

Anybody know of a workaround for this situation?